# How do I deploy application on sourcevoid with private git package dependencies?

Tags: dart

Deploying an application on [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com/) with private git package dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  some_package:
    git: someprivateurl.git
```

will not work because the [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com/) container does not have access to your private git url.  It can only deploy private repos on github and pull the source just fine.

Comment: I wanted to tag this with sourcevoid but could not because my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying a snapshot, built locally, works:

```
dart --snapshot=path/to/snapshot path/to/application
```

Deploying the snapshot version allows [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com/) to pull the application without the need to pull the source from the private package repo.

An example of a [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com/) application using a dart snapshot can be found here: https://github.com/damondouglas/hello-shelf-snapshot.  Note, this example doesn't not depend on a private package repo but would work just the same.

I suggest you maintain an additional `build` branch in the application repo.  The pubspec in `master` references the private git repo dependency.  The pubspec in `build` does not.  [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com/) allows you to specify which branch of a git repo to use when deploying so I would just point to the `build` repo.