# Deploying snapshot application in sourcevoid results in "Wrong script snapshot version, expected '...' found '...'

Tags: dart

Some applications require deploying a snapshot to [sourcevoid](https://www.sourcevoid.com) (see [How do I deploy application on sourcevoid with private git package dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536420/)).  When deploying such application, I received the error:

`Wrong script snapshot version, expected '181c54397e255f0b57b3cbca6f22607a' found '67ac118c5ca5a680109da82693316e0c'`

Comment: I wanted to tag this with sourcevoid but could not because my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `sourcevoid.yaml` version matches the version of dart on the machine used to build the snapshot.  For those starting out with dart, you can find the version of dart in your favorite terminal by typing:

```
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 1.17.1 (Fri Jun 10 04:46:03 2016) on "macos_x64"
```

Match the `n.n.n` number showing in the version output in your `sourcevoid.yaml` as shown below:

sourcevoid.yaml:

```
runtime: dart
version: 1.17.1
start: dart path/to/snapshot
```